# How do i give permissions from GCP to Firebase Functions to access resources? (like GCE)

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

does anyone know how do i give permission from my project in GCP to a function created and deployed in firebase? Because what i'm doing is the following:

1. From a site (deployed also in firebase) y call to the backend (Firebase Function)
2. The function itself, tries to get resources from my GCP project (in specific what instances are currently running)
3. Then, i receive them and show on the front.

The step 2 is causing my problems, currently when i'm trying to run it, it gives me the error:
**Error: could not handle the request** and in the log from firebase function i got: **GaxiosError: Required 'compute.instances.list' permission for 'projects/projectID'** so i know for sure that's a problem of authorization.

All this project worked just well 2 months ago, but my free trial expired and we tried to move to another GCP account and try to finish this project (With this i know the code works just right, the problem is for sure GCP because also, when i use others API ENDPOINTS not related to GCP resources, they work just well).

Any recomendation would be amazing, and if i didn't gave enough info just tell me. Thanks u for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an IAM role containing the required permission to the Cloud Function service account.

For example the role `roles/compute.viewer` has the permission `compute.instances.list`.

Review this page to learn more about Compute Engine IAM roles:

[Compute Engine IAM roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam)

Firebase Functions are Cloud Functions. Cloud Functions uses the `App Engine default service account` for access control. The format of the service account's name is: `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. Find that service account under IAM and add the role mentioned above.

[Cloud Functions Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam)

Comment: Thanks u so much for your help. The problem was that the Functions were on a different project on GCP. So, i enabled the GCE API on that project and created an instance, and it worked correctly. Now my new question is: It's possible use Functions from project "B" to access resources from project "A"? Again ty for your helpful answer.

Comment: Yes. In project A, go to IAM. Add the App Engine service account email address from Project B. Assign the required roles.